# Automate site with API response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, automation

So I made an webapp using the Instagram API and I get back a two arrays.  1 for the user information, and another for photos in the area. Due the amount of users that visit our site, I serve a static json file to the server to prevent going over our API limit and to cut down on loading time.

My problem is that I work for a company and it'd be really nice if I didn't have to manually run the script to generate the content, and copy and paste that content into our json file and upload it to our server.

A "trick" I'm aware of is to create a setTimeout (or setInterval) function to only perform a live update of content at a specific time of day, but how can I do better?

What is considered best practice when trying to automate an API response update?   Specifically, the app is written in client-side javascript.  As far as server-side, I know NodeJS. My assumption is that I would write server-side logic to perform this, again though, all files are ultimately uploaded to my company's server via FTP.

Comment: Shouldn't this be done on the company's server?

Comment: not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve.  Are you attempted to automatically update your site in browser at certain intervals?  Are you attempting to make an API response dynamic?  What?

Comment: @hownowbrowncow I apologize for the vagueness, and thank you for your help.  I'm trying to dynamically make a call to an API endpoint, and then have the browser update at certain intervals with the new information.

Comment: Wait, your problem is to update your JSON file (on company's server) everyday via FTP. Am I right?

Comment: @PierreC. Yes.  As it stands, everday, I run a script that generates new content and I upload to our company's server.  I would like this to be done automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is basically to schedule a task, like cron on Linux.

I have never tried them but I suggest you take a look at these two Node.JS modules:

- [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)
- [ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp)

#### What you have to do then:

- Create a dayly job with node-schedule
- In the job callback, make your request to your API
- Save JSON data to a file
- Send that file to the company's server with the ftp module

#### Requirements:

- The machine hosting the Node.JS server **must** be awake at all time (or atleast when the cron job is going to fire) **AND** your node application **must** be started aswell.

In my opinion, it would be way more relevant to create the job on the server. The server is (generally) up all the time so you do not have to worry about that. And you remove the FTP usage because you save your file directly on the server.

Comment: I believe that to be the most elegant solution.  Per, though per it's documentation, it states: "If you need to schedule jobs that will persist even when your script isn't running, consider using actual cron."  Could you elaborate on your opinion statement at the end? I'm assuming you're saying, get in touch with the Dev's that maintain the company server and work with them?